# serialize in .NET, deserialize in C++

Tags: c#, c++, serialization

I have a .NET application which serializes an object in binary format.
this object is a struct consisting of a few fields.

I must deserialize and use this object in a C++ application.
I have no idea if there are any serialization libraries for C++, a google search hasn't turned up much.

What is the quickest way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.
Roey.

Update : 
I have serialized using Protobuf-net , in my .NET application, with relative ease.
I also get the .proto file that protobuf-net generated, using GetProto() command.
In the .proto file, my GUID fields get a type of "bcl.guid", but C++ protoc.exe compiler does not know how to interpret them!
What do I do with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `BinaryFormatter`, then it will be virtually impossible. Don't go there...

Protocol buffers is *designed* to be portable, cross platform and version-tolerant (so it won't explode when you add new fields etc). Google provide the C++ version, and there are several C# versions freely available (including my own) - [see here for the full list](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns).

Small, fast, easy.

Note that the v1 of protobuf-net won't handle structs *directly* (you'll need a DTO class), but v2 (very soon) *does* have tested struct support.

Comment: Hi Marc, sorry for abusing this comment section, but I've run into an issue with protobuf-net - could you take a look at my post and maybe answer? thanks :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370090/protobuf-net-serializing-net-guid-how-to-read-this-in-c

Comment: @Roey - cheers for drawing my attention to it, but I already have an RSS feed for anything tagged `protobuf-net` ;-p

Answer (score 7):

Can you edit the .NET app? If so why not use [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx) to output the data in a easy to import format?

Comment: Probably the easiest way... even though XML is evil.

Answer (score 1):

Both boost and Google have libraries for serialization.  However, if your struct is pretty trivial, you might consider managing the serialization yourself by writing bytes out from C# and then reading the data in C++ with fread.

Comment: When I binary serialize in .NET, does it not write bytes in a way that would be readable with C++ fread?

Comment: Oh I see what you meant, you need me to read each field seperately from the stream and put it into a variable in my C++ program....

Comment: Yes, and if your structure is simple enough with LayoutKind.Sequential, you could probably just blit the whole thing out in .NET and read it one go in in C++.  This is assuming you're only using PODs like int, double, etc in your struct.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with others. You are making your app very vulnerable by doing this. Consider the situation if one of the classes you're serializing is changed in any way or built on a later version of the C# compiler: Your serialized classes could potentially change causing them to be unreadable.

An XML based solution might work well. Have you considered SOAP? A little out of fashion now but worth a look. The main issue is to decouple the implementation from the data. You can do this in binary if speed / efficiency is an issue, although in my experience, it rarely is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option of changing the format? If so, consider choosing a non-binary format for greater interoperability. There are plenty of libraries for reading and writing XML. Json is popular as well.

Binary formats are efficient, but vulnerable to implementation details (does your C++ compiler pack data structures? how are ints and floats represented? what byte ordering is used?), and difficult to adjust if mangled. Text based formats are verbose, but tend to be much more robust. If you are uncertain about binary representations, text representations tend to be easier to understand (apart from challenges such as code pages and wide/narrow characters...).

For C++ XML libraries, the most capable (and perhaps also most complex) would still seem to be the [Xerces library](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/). But you should decide for yourself [which library best fits your needs and skills](http://www.google.com/search?q=xml+c%2B%2B+library).

Comment: I am compiling both .NET and c++ with VS2008, I do not know the answers to your questions...
If I use XML, can you please recommend a C++ library to deserialize it? 
If I decide to stick with binaries, can C++ understand a .NET serialized binary struct?

Comment: If you're not sure about the binary representations, you will run into trouble. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Serializing in a binary format and expecting an application in another language to read the binary is a very brittle solution (ie it will tend to break on the smallest change to anything).

It would be more stable to serialize the data in a common standard format.

Comment: As long as the binary is in an agreed format, this doesn't have to be brittle *at all*. But yes - things like `BinaryFormatter` are doomed to fail here.

Comment: @Mark: Yes and no. Formats are agreed upon based on the binary representation of the structure. If anything changes like the endianess of an integer (change in hardware) padding between elements (update in compiler) etc the biary structure now no longer matches the original. A straight port of the C++ program with a new compiler or on a new machines has the potential to break. The worst thing is that a standard implementation would not be able to detect the change and may silently do the wrong thing.

Comment: Not to forget the integer size. In a recent application at my shop, we serialized data using `Boost.Serialization` on a 32 bit machine and de-serialized it on a 64 bit machine and it wrecked havoc. So yes, binary formats are, indeed, brittle.

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Serialization its the best way to go, in fact is the cleanest way to go.

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer( typeof( YourClassType ) );
TextWriter w = new StreamWriter( @"c:\list.xml" );
s.Serialize( w, yourClassListCollection );
w.Close();
```

Comment: XML serialization is cleanest but it is also the slowest and not suitable where time is of critical importance.