# Using protocol buffers to interface c# and c++

Tags: c++, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I've got a large solution written in c# that uses protobuf-net library for communication. I'm looking to write a c++ program to talk to the existing code, and I'm close to being able to see how to do it.

Here's the plan:

1) Since everything was started in c#, there's no .proto files. However, I can easily write some code that captures the .proto from the existing message classes (GetProto).

2) Some of the types are non-standard, ie they are defined in terms of other types: bcl.DateTime and bcl.Decimal, for example. Using this link I was able to find the definitions: [Protobuf-net - serializing .NET GUID - how to read this in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370090/protobuf-net-serializing-net-guid-how-to-read-this-in-c)

3) Once I have the proto definitions, I can just run the Google code to generate my classes, which will need some extra code to deal with non-standard stuff. Not a big deal.

**My only issue at the moment is the format of dictionaries/maps.** They look something like this:

```
repeated Pair_Decimal_Int32 MyDict = 1
```

What I need is to know is how this special type is defined. It is of course linked to generics (depends on the dictionary), so perhaps there's special code that generates it? I can't quite tell where in protobuf-net it deals with this, so I'm looking for some help.

Comment: I'd guess that `Pair_Decimal_Int32` is just a simple message with two fields (a `double` and an `int32`?), my guess is they're named "first" and "second".  There's nothing generic in protocol buffers, you'd have to deal with that when processing the message into your dictionary.

Comment: Well, I suppose the Decimal would be bcl.Decimal and the Int32 would be whatever that maps to. Makes sense. Why do obvious things stare me in the face like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the GetProto in v2 is very newly implemented (as in: days ago) and may have rough edges (it is marked as such).

For datetimes, I would suggest thinking about exposing those as a simpler type for the purposes of interop - maybe a long (ticks into epoch). Dictionaries are simply repeated versions of key (field 1) / value (field 2). Decimal also doesn't have a nice representation in raw protobuf; if possible, use long (scaled by a fixed value) or double, IMO.

Comment: @Franchesca yes, I wrote that one evening last week. Needs more testing, but passes the initial tests.

Comment: ok, consider me as your own personal tester ;) I'm working on this full time now, so will let you know if I find any issues.

Comment: @Franchesca note I haven't deployed that to nuget/google-code; you'd have t build from source. I can put a package together later today if you need

Comment: Ah, it's ok, I already have your source checked out from trunk. For now I will just use it like this for testing / debugging, but once I'm using it in production (that will be a few weeks at least, so no rush) it would be awesome to have it deployed to nuget. Thanks!!! <333

Comment: one more thing, can I just open issues I find [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/list)?

Comment: What's new? Will it break stuff? I was using only very simple functionality from the V1, just tagging and serializing.

Also, I never quite understood how to start with .proto files. It would be easier to have the .NET versions doing the conversion than the c++ version.

Comment: @Carlos "will it break stuff" - it certainly shouldn't! The entire v1 API is retained, so you shouldn't even need any changes. "what's new" - the entire core has been re-written, allowing it to be much more efficient, allowing full external pre-compilation, allowing models to be defined at runtime (rather than just via attributes). Additionally, all new features are only going into v2 - tuple support, surrogate support, factory support, proxy support, etc... But for basic models: other than marginally faster, you might not notice it has changed

Comment: Thanks Marc. And how do I use .proto files instead of tagging? I never found an example.

Comment: @Carlos you don't. A .proto file can be used to **generate** c# classes (or other languages/platforms) that meet the schema defined in the .proto; they aren't simply an alternative to tagging. It is like saying "how do I use an xsd file to avoid having to add XML-attributes" - you don't : you use the xsd to *generate* c# with attributes. That said, v2 does support usage without attributes... Just - it is unrelated to .proto

Comment: I suppose what I mean is given a .proto file, how do I generate the classes? That's what the Google stuff does, but in your paradigm you tag the classes and create the schema from there.

Comment: @Carlos you need the "protogen" tool, included in the google-code package. Then just "protogen -i:your.proto -o:your.cs", or something like that (I, sure -? will reveal the syntax). Alternatively, there's a VS add-in, in which case it should process the .proto automatically whenever it is altered and saved.

Comment: Cool, I'll have a look at that. Oh wait, I know what to do with the Google stuff. But that's for the c++ side. How do I generate c# code using protobuf-net and a .proto file?

Comment: @Carlos exactly what I just said :) note I said "protogen", not "protoc".